# Random sampling error vs. test statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, sample

I've been told many times in my school, that after you analyze your data and get statistically significant results, you can say that the result is not due to chance and therefore you can conclude that **you can find this effect in a whole population**.

I am confused by this. How can you conclude that in context of randomized experiment, when you clearly don't have the representative sample of population. Do you actually use test statistics in this context for internal validity purpose? Can you say that (with certain probability) you would see the same result in (for example) 95 % of following experiments?

Example: You have sample of 20 subjects (which can be students from university). Then you randomly assing them to the treatment and control state. Both groups do statistically differ in mean value of Y. But does it mean that the effect of the treatment will hold in the whole human population OR does it only means that the effect is not due to chance among this exact sample?

Thank you.

Comment: One of the purposes of a randomized sample is to get a representative sample from the population - choosing all the subjects from a university is not a random sample, even if you assign them to the treatment and control groups randomly. Have a look at [RCTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_controlled_trial) for more detail

Comment: But you rarely have a random sample in your experiment, yet test statistics are being used and I am not sure for what purpose - what exactly is achieved by the test?

Comment: You can extrapolate your results to the subpopulation your sample is drawn from, but not much more. Small tests on biased samples are useful for proof of concept; they can be necessary for showing that your method is worth funding a larger test. Sometimes you only care about the subpopulation anyway, e.g. if your sample came from hospital patients, or people with some specific characteristic. From a health perspective though, if I saw a study on 20 university students I wouldn't pay much attention to it.